# Potential step and its transmission / reflection

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering

Lets say we have a potential step with regions 1 with zero potential $W_p\!=\!0$ (this is a free particle) and region 2 with potential $W_p$. Wave functions in this case are:

\begin{align}
\psi_1&=Ae^{i\mathcal L x} + B e^{-i\mathcal L x} & \mathcal L &\equiv \sqrt{\frac{2mW}{\hbar^2}}\\
\psi_2&=De^{-\mathcal K x} & \mathcal K &\equiv \sqrt{\frac{2m(W_p-W)}{\hbar^2}}
\end{align}

Where $A$ is an amplitude of an incomming wave, $B$ is an amplitude of an reflected wave and $D$ is an amplitude of an transmitted wave. I have sucessfuly derived a relations between amplitudes in potential step:

\begin{align}
\frac{A}{D} &= \frac{i\mathcal L-\mathcal K}{2i\mathcal L} &  \frac{A}{B}&=-\frac{i \mathcal L - \mathcal K}{i \mathcal L + \mathcal K}
\end{align}

I know that if i want to calculate transmittivity coefficient $T$ or reflexifity coefficient $R$ i will have to use these two relations that i know from wave physics:

\begin{align}
T &= \frac{j_{trans.}}{j_{incom.}} & R &= \frac{j_{trans.}}{j_{incom.}}
\end{align}

---

**Question 1:** I know that $j = \frac{dm}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\rho V \propto \rho v  \propto \rho k$ But what is a density $\rho$ equal to?

**Question 2:** I noticed that $\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal K$ are somehow (i dont know how) connected to the wavevector $k$ from the equation in 1st question but how? How can i make it obvious?

Comment: Similar if not same to [quations/60228](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60228/wave-equations-for-two-intervals-at-potential-step?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Are you shore thats the definition of current you want? In quantum mechanics you have tho related concepts:

- Probability density defined by :$\rho = |\psi(x)|^2$
- Probability current: $\vec{j} = \frac{1}{m}\Re(\psi^*\hat{p}\psi) = \frac{\hbar}{2mi}(\psi^*\nabla \psi - \psi\nabla\psi^*) $
- Both concepts are related by a continuity equations: $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \vec{j} =0$ expresing the local conservation of probability. It's eassily derivable froma the top definitions and Schrödinger's equation.

Try using this concepts in the first part. The second part shoud follow.

### EDIT:

The operator nabla is definied as $\nabla = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z})$, so operationg over $\psi$ it would look as: $\nabla\psi = (\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x},\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y},\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial z})$. In the one dimensional problem you have, the operator is also one dimensional, so it is symply the position derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

Then the 1_D current is defined just as before, changin $\nabla$ for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. Thats the definition. The 'physical' picture is the flow of probability.

With continous estates (in the base of an operator with continous eigenvalues), the inner product is defined as :

$$\left<\psi\right|\phi\left. \right> = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi^*(x)\phi(x)  dx$$

so the probability of the state in $[a,b]$ is $$P([a,b])=\left<\phi [a,b]\right|\phi [a,b]\left. \right> = \int_{a}^b |\phi(x)|^2  dx$$

so you could define a local density so that integrating the density over $[a,b]$ gives the probability. With that we have that the density can be defined as $\rho=|\psi(x)|^2$

Comment: Isn't $|\psi|^2$ only a probability? I know jet nothing about probability current $j$. How is it defined? If possible i would perfer if you avoid $\nabla$ operator. I am not familiar with it yet.

Comment: I found a link on how to derive the probability current here: http://www.physics.ucdavis.edu/Classes/Physics115A/probcur.pdf It seems to me that he somehow messed a sign. It should be: $$\vec{j} = -\frac{\hbar i }{2m}(\psi^*\nabla \psi - \psi\nabla\psi^*)$$ Please confirm.

Comment: Now that i know $j$, how can i now get equations for $T$ and $R$?

Comment: @71GA: Both our definitions are the same, bear in mind that $-i = \frac{1}{i}$

Comment: I suggest you to take some book in intruductory quantum mechanics, like Mandl's Quantum Mechanics or Shankar's Princinciples of Quantum Mechanics. Both have the solution of the problem.

Comment: Why do averyone use $\psi_{2} = D e^{-i\mathcal K x}$ which looks like a sinus if i plot it in Wolfram alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7Bix%7D&t=crmtb01 . On the other hand i think that we should use $\psi_{2} = D e^{-\mathcal K x}$ which falls towards zero nicely: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7B-x%7D This makes no sense to me...

Comment: $e^{-iKx}$ is the complex exponential, in wolfram|alpha they shows you the conection between the exponential and the trig functions, with euler's formula. You cant use the one without $i$, as it istn`t the solution to your diferential ecuation. And you should bear in mind that thoose states are not normalized

Comment: But i am talking about potential step with only 2 regions. Not 3.